# Software raid 1 on ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, raid, initramfs

I am trying to setup Sofware RAID 1 for my ubuntu desktop (14.04)
Unfortunately desktop installer no longer supports RAID1 configuration. Therefore I am trying to manually set this up.

I followed this [blog post](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-10.04-p2) with following changes:

- set root='(md/0)'
- Added insmod mdraid1x instead of raid
- I do not have separate boot partition ( /dev/md0 is set to / )

When I try to boot using /dev/md0 , I am dropped to busybox shell with following error:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: no such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: no such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: no such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
```

I ran `cat /proc/mdstat` in initramfs which shows all three devices are active.

`mount /dev/md0 /root` works fine and I can see the filesystem mounted.

I found following in `dmesg` :

```
md: bind<sdb6>
    md0: unknown partition table
```

I am really stuck with this and trying to find solution since couple of days. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The server installer can still be used to install on software raid, though the text only interface is somewhat difficult to understand. You have to first create raid partitions, then jump to the "configure software raid" sub menu. Once your system is installed, just `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to turn your server installation into a desktop installation.

Comment: Is ubuntu-desktop package only difference between server and desktop edition? I believe kernels are also tweaked differently for each use cases.

Comment: as stated on [ubuntu faq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F), there is no kernel difference between desktop and server edition since ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @exore Ended up using Ubuntu server installer.